# Loaded dynamically svg

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to dynamically import a svg, I can not manage to display the svg in my HTML page i used Angular js:
i have  this code : 
Directive.js :

```
angular.module ('SvgMapApp') directive ('svgMap', ['$ compile', function ($ compile) {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         templateUrl: 'Scripts/widget.svg',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            
         }
     }
}]);
```

Svg.Html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FrontEnd/Styles.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" />

</head>
<body ng-app="SvgApplication" ng-controller="svgController">
    <h1> SVG widget</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
    <div svg></div>
</div>
    <script src="Scripts/Controller.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

have you an idea please

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of syntax errors to begin with. Your code probably throws an error and never runs.

1. The directive declaration:

   ```
   angular.module ('SvgMapApp') directive ('svgMap', ['$ compile', function ($ compile) {
   ```

   Should be

   ```
   angular.module('SvgMapApp').directive ('svgMap', ['$', 'compile', function ($, compile) {
   ```
2. `compile` should be `$compile` (if you want to use the built-in [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service).
3. `<div svg></div>` should be `<div svg-map></div>`. AngularJS transforms your directive name `svgMap` to `svg-map` and that's the attribute you have to use in your templates in order to render the directive.

Also would not load an SVG element as `templateUrl`. You are better of creating an HTML template and inlining your SVG element inside it.

Comment: Hello for all 
Have you an idea please